# Can you embed an image in a Nodemailer email without also having the image attached to the email?

Tags: image, nodemailer

I am successfully following the Nodemailer documentation to embed an image in the email from my app.  As listed in the documentation, the image also shows up as an attachment to the email.  So it's attached to the email, and embedded in the body of the email.
Is there a way to have the image embedded in the email body, but not also included as a separate attachment?  I find the extra attachment is distracting.
Thank you!
Jon